# A file container for storing two lossless images?

Tags: scanning

I am scanning my card collection, and for each card I'm scanning the front and back. Now I'm looking for a file container that can store them into one single file, and this file should also be able to read by image viewer with thumbnail.

What are my options for this? The first thing that comes to mind is pdf, but I don't think it stores lossless images like png. A zip is able to store lossless but it couldn't be read by image viewer and no thumbnails on Windows.

Comment: Might you be okay with just combining the two images into a single image?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about photography, it's about storage mechanisms/image combination.

Comment: @EricS No, I want them to be able to extract as well

Comment: If you are looking for an actual piece of software you might want to post this question on Software Recommendations SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible option is to use TIFF format. It support multipage and also can use different compression algorithm, lossy and lossless. Also it support different colour spaces and embedded thumbnails

Comment: How do I do that? I only know about tiff from photoshop, it can only store images as layers, not multipage.

Comment: @reddy, I use xnview MP, select images->Create->Multi-page file->select proper name, path, format

Comment: Thanks, I tested it out for a while and it looks to be a good solution. I threw in two png and the program was able to convert them to multipage tiff with comparable file size using the `LZW + Predictor` compression algorithm. And Windows photo viewer was able to read it and the file is showing thumbnail. The only downside is that it will convert everything to 24 bit depth even with lossless chosen for a 48 bit source.

Comment: @reddy, you can report this as bug/problem on the software forum